# How can I provide activity context with Dagger dependecies?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dependencies, dagger-2

**How can I provide activity context in mainModule class ? Thanks!** The code looks like this:

```
    @Singleton
@Component(modules = {AndroidInjectionModule.class, AppModule.class, ActivityBuilder.class})
public interface AppComponent {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        Builder application(Application application);

        AppComponent build();

    }

    void inject(MvmApp app);
}
```

Activtity builder:

```
@Module
public abstract class ActivityBuilder {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = {MainModule.class})
    abstract MainActivity bindMainActivity();
}
```

And I have an appModule, and a module for each activity:

```
@Module
public class AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @ApplicationContext
    Context provideContext(Application application) {
        return application;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    DataManager provideDataManager(AppDataManager appDataManager) {
        return appDataManager;
    }

    @Provides
    @DatabaseInfo
    String provideDatabaseName() {
        return "carDatabase";
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    AppDataBase provideAppDatabase(@DatabaseInfo String dbName, @ApplicationContext Context context) {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDataBase.class, dbName)
                .build();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    DbHelper provideDbHelper(AppDbHelper appDbHelper) {
        return appDbHelper;
    }
}
```

AppClass:

```
public class MvmApp extends Application implements HasActivityInjector {

    @Inject
    DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> activityDispatchingAndroidInjector;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .application(this)
                .build()
                .inject(this);

    }

    @Override
    public DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> activityInjector() {
        return activityDispatchingAndroidInjector;
    }
}
```

All my activities extends a base activity which inject the Dagger dependecies.

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MvpView {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        AndroidInjection.inject(this);

    }
}
```

***In mainModule I need to provide the context of the activity.***

```
@Module
public class MainModule {

    @Provides
    MainMvpPresenter<MainMvpView> provideMainPresenter(
            MainPresenter<MainMvpView> presenter) {
        return presenter;
    }



    @Provides
    CompositeDisposable provideCompositeDisposable() {
        return new CompositeDisposable();
    }

    @Provides
    CarAdapter provideCarAdapter( @ActivityContext Context context) {
        return new CarAdapter(context);
    }

}
```

Comment: You don't need to inject dependencies in each Activity. Just make your BaseActivity extend DaggerAppCompatActivity

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution was:

```
@Module
public class MainModule {

    @Provides
    MainMvpPresenter<MainMvpView> provideMainPresenter(
            MainPresenter<MainMvpView> presenter) {
        return presenter;
    }

    @Provides
    CompositeDisposable provideCompositeDisposable() {
        return new CompositeDisposable();
    }

    @Provides
    CarAdapter provideCarAdapter(MainActivity activity) {
        return new CarAdapter(activity);
    }

}
```

Comment: So you have to create a module for each activity?

Comment: @L.Dan: how to provide activity instance in more than 1 service?

Answer (score 2):

For people facing a similar issue, I've made a project with Kotlin, and the new `android-dagger` extension with a lengthy explanation on how things work over here: https://github.com/Obaied/BareBonesAndroidDagger

Comment: If you read question carefully @L.Dan wants to use context from ActivityModule not Activity itself. To use one module in different Activity, maybe we have to use just Context not concrete activity.